# Wrapping ListView inside rectangle

Tags: qt, listview, qml

My problem is when i scroll ListView elements , the elements scroll over the rectangle border however i have wrapped the ListView inside the Rectangle.How can i make elements scroll without effecting the Rectangle borders.

Here are the result links
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx616yTb6y_xQzNxRy1UcktrVzA/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx616yTb6y_xdl9CbWt4MTJ3Smc/view?usp=sharing

Following is the code

```
        ListModel{
        id: mod
    }
        Rectangle{
        id:listviewrec
        x: 347
        y:644
        width: 700
        height: 91
        radius: 4
        border.color:"#7CC7FF"
        border.width: 4
         visible: true

            ListView{
                id:modlistview
                width: listviewrec.width
                height: listviewrec.height
                clip: true
                boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
                spacing:25
                model:mod
                delegate: delegateimage
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                anchors.fill: listviewrec


            }

        }


    Component{
        id:delegateimage
        Item{
            id:imageitem
            width:50
            height:60
            visible:true
            Rectangle{
                id:imagerec
                x:10
                y:6
                width: 60
                height:70                    
                border.color: "#7CC7FF"
                border.width: 5
                radius: 2
                visible:true
                Image{
                    x: 3
                    y: 3
                    height : imagerec.height
                    visible: true
                    width : imagerec.width
                    anchors.fill: imagerec
                    source:fileUrl
                }
                                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think qml has the concept of inner- and outer- rects as far as borders are concerned, (or if it does, borders are drawn in the inner-rect so children will be drawn on top).

Your best bet here is to probably do something like this:

```
Item {
  id:listviewrec
  x: 347
  y:644
  width: 700
  height: 91
  visible: true

  ListView{
    id:modlistview
    width: listviewrec.width
    height: listviewrec.height
    clip: true
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
    spacing:25
    model:mod
    delegate: delegateimage
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    anchors.fill: listviewrec
  }

  Rectangle {
    radius: 4
    border.color:"#7CC7FF"
    border.width: 4
    color: 'transparent'
    anchors.fill: parent
  }
}
```

It simply draws a transparent rect with the border you want on top of the ListView

Comment: Thanks alot it works fine now :) can you give me clue how i can add header and footer so that when user clicks on header the listview elements moves left and clicking upon footer moves right .

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am unable to run your code, but it seems a matter of removing explicit width and height settings, since you are using anchors.fill